# (swift OSX) how to change datepicker era designator

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

How to set era designator in datepicker.
thank for advice

[View image click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eqyU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust your date picker's minDate and maxDate properties 
according to Apple documentation see below:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDatePicker_Class/index.html